# Vuetify v-data-table not showing singleSelection | Vue 2

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I follow the documentation for row-selection in vuetify 2 website.
https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort

However, after attempting to create a single-row selection, the generated v-data-table does not have the checkbox and instead, have an empty space.

Here are the codes for review.

```
<template>
    <v-data-table 
      v-model="selected"
      hide-default-footer
      :headers="headers" 
      :items="tutorials"
      :single-select="singleSelection"
      item-key="title"    
      show-select
    > 
    </v-data-table>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "tutorials-list",
  data() {
    return {
      singleSelection: true,
      selected: [],
      // tutorials: [],      

      headers: [
        {
          text: "Title",
          align: "end",
          value: 'title',
          key: "title",
        },
        {
          text: "Description",
          align: "start",
          value: "description",
          key: "description",
        },
        {
          text: "Status",
          align: "end",
          value: 'published',
          key: "published",
        },
      ],

      tutorials: [{
          title: "Tutorial #1",
          description: "description 1",
          published: false
        },
        {
          title: "Tutorial #2",
          description: "description 2",
          published: true
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The generated v-data-table for reference.
[Missing single selection option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAYDq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve by re-downloading the vuetify project via CLI.

" vue add vuetify "

The reason was the "Vuetify" missing this import.
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';